# Getting a src from an img tag using beautifulsoup

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-3.5, discord.py

This is my last cry for help I'm trying to do some cool embedding with my discord bot and the only problem is I can't seem to get the img from the website to work can anyone help? For the most part, this is what other people have told me to use and the codes found here are not working.

```
async def events(self, ctx):
    """Top GTAO bounses going on right now!"""

    if ctx.message.server.me.bot:
        try:
            await self.bot.delete_message(ctx.message)
        except:
            await self.bot.send_message(ctx.message.author, 'Could not delete your message on ' + ctx.message.server.name)

    url = "https://socialclub.rockstargames.com/" 

    async with aiohttp.get(url) as response:
        soupObject = BeautifulSoup(await response.text(), "html.parser")

    try:
        rm = "[Read More](https://socialclub.rockstargames.com/events)"
        img = "https://i.imgur.com/0Gu4sSK.png"
        avi = "https://i.imgur.com/s5O1yD2.png"
        bonus1 = soupObject.find(class_='bonuses').find('ul').get_text()
        evpic = soupObject.find(class_='eventThumb').find('img').get('src')
        # EMBED
        data = discord.Embed(title='GTA Online Bonuses', description='The Current GTA Online Bonuses', colour=0xE4BA22)
        data.set_author(name='Rockstar Games', icon_url=avi)
        data.add_field(name="This week: \n", value=bonus1)
        data.add_field(name="--------", value=rm)
        data.set_image(url=evpic)
        data.set_thumbnail(url=img)
        a`enter code here`wait self.bot.say(embed=data)


    except discord.HTTPException:
        await self.bot.say("I need the `Embed links` permission to send this OR error")
```

Comment: Which part of this doesn't work?

Comment: Try `evpic = soupObject.find('img', {'class' : 'eventThumb'} )['src']`

Comment: i got TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: No one? is this a rip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the website, Rockstar doesn't use the `src` tag in their images because it is handled by some internal JS

```
>>> soup.find(attrs={'class':'eventThumb'})
<div class="eventThumb">
<img class="lazyload" data-src="https://prod.cloud.rockstargames.com/global/Events/20449/829a53e7-d14e-4de8-a17b-ccb06becfed6.jpg"/>
</div>
>>> _.img
<img class="lazyload" data-src="https://prod.cloud.rockstargames.com/global/Events/20449/829a53e7-d14e-4de8-a17b-ccb06becfed6.jpg"/>
>>> _.get('data-src')
'https://prod.cloud.rockstargames.com/global/Events/20449/829a53e7-d14e-4de8-a17b-ccb06becfed6.jpg'
```

So to fix, you would need to change your `.get('src')` to a `.get('data-src')`

Comment: Works! Thank you!!